# jQuery syntax - use more than one find method?

Tags: jquery

The below code clones the last row in my table and clears the data shown in the SPANs. There is also some hidden INPUTs (because it's data table) so my question is, how do I do another find i.e. `.find(".getdata input")` in this block of code?

```
var i = 1;
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("table tr:last").clone().find(".getdata span").each(function() {
        $(this).text('');
    }).end().appendTo("table");
    i++;
});
```

Comment: ignore the var i - I forgot to to delete

Comment: what do you want to do with that hidden inputs?

Comment: just clear their data

Comment: `.clone().find(".getdata span,input:hidden").each...` just use a `,` separator.

Comment: @ShaunakD Then you need to check the type of elements inside the call back since `.text()` is not applicable for `input` elements

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Right.!! Good catch :)

Comment: @shaunak d, thanks - i didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a better way by caching the cloned element,

```
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    var clone = $("table tr:last").clone();
    $(".getdata span", clone).text("");
    $("input[type=hidden]", clone).val("");
    clone.appendTo("table");
});
```

And there is no need to iterate over all the elements to set its text/value. Jquery will do it for you under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain them

```
var i = 1;
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("table tr:last").clone().find(".getdata span").each(function() {
        $(this).text('');
    }).end()
    .find(".getdata input").each(function() {
       //do other stuf here
    }).end().appendTo("table");
    i++;
});
```